# Unable to find Restore Database Option in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, database-restore, ssms-2014

I am trying to restore a .bak file in my SQL Server using SSMS.
However I am unable to find the Restore Database option in the menu bar, when I right-clicked on Database.
[image]

What can be the possible reason for that?
Do I need to change some SSMS settings. 
I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2014.

Comment: It looks like you don't have permissions to restore a database on that instance.

Comment: It seems that the SQL server I am connected to is in Azure. I am able to restore the .Bak file in my local DB but I am not getting the option in SQL Server. Can it be an op-prem vs SQL Server issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not possible to restore a .bak file to an Azure SQL Database.  To migrate data to an Azure SQL Database, see this documentation: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-cloud-migrate/

Comment: That seems to be the issue, cause I was able to restore the bak file in the local SQL Server. Need to look for ways to migrate the DB from local to Azure SQL. Thanks for the clarification.